# Image to right on mouseover

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-popover

I have an image I want to appear when a user hovers over a link.

Example:

```
<a href="/something">Some anchor text</a> with some extra text.
```

Basic anchor, no frills.

I want to display an image to the right (or left) of the link when the user hovers over the link **without displacing anything else**.  I was trying to find some JSFiddle examples or some library to use but couldn't find anything.

Desired output is something like this (but with a bit more flare):

[image: sample output]

I'm trying to get this to work with any configuration of the DOM (not just text) and I keep winding up with solutions that push the text around or (as a side-effect) rearrange my divs. I wanted to try to use a frameless [Bootstrap Popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#popovers) but I couldn't figure out how to style an individual popover scenario to do that.

I'm 100% not a UI guy so I'm sure my [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=anchor%20mouseover%20display%20image%20to%20side%20on%20top%20of%20all%20content&oq=anchor%20mouseover%20display%20image%20to%20side%20on%20top%20of%20all%20content) is phrased incorrectly.

Comment: I am **trying** to fiddle with https://popper.js.org at the moment to see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

https://jsfiddle.net/90hLs1ae/

I used a combination of [Tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/themes/) and custom CSS to control Tippy.

The important piece is making the background color transparent and the border as zero:

**CSS**

```
.tippy-tooltip.i-be-testing-theme {
  border: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

**Popup Setup**

```
tippy(document.getElementById('i-am-link'),
      {
        content: template,
        arrow: false,
        placement: 'right',
        theme: 'i-be-testing'
      }
);
```